# Creating SSL sertificate with trusted CA

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm not quite sure if this question applies to this forum but if it does maybe someone knows if it is possible using Open SSL to create a SSL sertificate that browsers wouldn't throw warning messadges that our created SSL sertificate is untrusted?

Comment: If this is for use within your **own** system/intranet etc you can create the self signed cert under a CA you create and manually add it to the trusted root CA store on a machine-by-machine basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically it is possible if you have CA's private key to sign the newly created certificate. As you probably don't have a key, the answer is probably no. Just go ahead and purchase a certificate from one of CAs. If you do minimal research, you will find that some CAs offer very affordable prices.

Comment: Mayevski 'EldoS so I can create an open sll sertificate, and buy a CA that would be cheaper than buying lets say Verisign SSl certificate??

Comment: @user605596 sorry, but your understanding is wrong. You can't "buy a CA". You (roughly speaking) purchase the certificate from trusted certificate authority such as Comodo or GlobalSign (they are cheaper yet well-known and well-trusted). Your other option to become a known CA is way more expensive than this. And unless you control client browsers (eg. in closed corporate environment), you can't magically make the clients trust your self-generated certificate. Technical aspect of how to generate a certificate using OpenSSL is a secondary question.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably better handled on server fault, but I will tell you that **NO** you cannot do this. The reason browsers don't like your certificate is that **you** are not a recognized certificate authority. As such, a browser will always warn about your certificate being untrustworthy, since the browser does not know who you are, or why anyone should trust you.

**EDIT**: As Alex K points out, you can install your certificate on machines you know will access your site, which works reasonably well for scenarios where the site will only be accessed by a limited number of known users/machines. My point still stands regarding wider distribution. Thanks, Alex.

Comment: have you heard about STARTSLL certificate A FREE SSL WHICH PROVIDES A BETTER PROTECTION THAN YOUR PAID VERISIGN,COMODO AND GODAAADY ant there are no warning messages, because STARTSSL IS A TRUSTED CA. @dlev